# How to create reports in google analytics for GA4-Google merchandise store

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

I am unable to create custom reports for GA4 - Google merchandise store in google analytics? The customization option is disabled. I am trying to use the demo data to play around and create custom reports. Why is that and how to do this?